# remove fill color levels from a ggplotly legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Is there a way to remove the fill color from the `ggplotly` legend since it is redundant with the facet? In other words, it's true that I essentially have four combinations, but I only want to show the levels of alpha in the legend because the faceting tells you the same information as the fill values. I don't need to explain what red and green mean since red only applies to facet `group3==0` and green only applies to facet `group3==1`.

[image]

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r}
  library(tidyverse)
  library(plotly)
  library(flexdashboard)
```


### Chart 1

```{r}
  f <- list(family = "Poppins")
  a <- list(tickfont = f)

  p <- fortify(forecast::gold) %>%
       mutate(group1 = sample(0:1, n(), replace=TRUE),
              group2 = sample(0:1, n(), replace=TRUE),
              group3 = sample(0:1, n(), replace=TRUE)
              ) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(factor(group1), y, alpha=factor(group2), fill=factor(group3))) + 
         geom_col() + 
         scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.5, 1)) +
         facet_wrap(~group3)

  ggplotly(p)
```
````

Comment: What colors would you expect to see in the legend?

Comment: If I reduce the lower alpha to 0 I think it would be clear with a label showing white and grey fill to represent no fill and fill.

Comment: And add an outline

Comment: Ultimately, I don't think this is possible in plotly, based on the way the legend interacts with the plots.  You can remove some of the levels from the legend, or recolor them, but you can't have red and blue for the plot and black and grey for the legend.  It's probably also not the best practice in data visualization to have a legend that doesn't align with data.

Comment: I can appreciate that. I have an easier time explaining with words the meaning of fill vs no fill (or semi-transparent).

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here from google because a ggplot that *didn't* have a legend was being given one when `ggplotly()` was called on it.

In case that affects anyone else, the answer is, use:

```
theme(legend.position='none')
```

as plotly understands that.